# React State - Unable to update the state

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Update: Fixed it. It was a schoolboy error. I had actually declared a const **BaseObject = () =>** in the render function, and then I was using return  in render function. Sorry for wasting your time guys. I moved the const outside as function, and everything is fine.

I have a very simple state:

```
this.state = {
    filters: [{ key: '', value: '' }, { key: '', value: '' }]
}
```

And part of render method is:

```
<div>
                {
                this.state.filters.map((filter, index) => {

                    return <div key={'filter_parent_div_'+index} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <AutoComplete key={'filter_auto'+index}  className='width30 sane-margin-from-right' data={keys} onItemSelected={this.onKeySelected(index)} label='Filter'/>
                            <div key={'filter_div_'+index} className='sane-margin-from-right width30'>
                                <FormattedTextbox
                                    id={'filterValue_'+index}
                                    key={'filter_text_'+index}
                                    type='text'
                                    label='Filter Value'
                                    defaultValue={filter.value}
                                    onChange={this.filterTextChanged(index)}>
                                </FormattedTextbox>
                            </div>
                            { index > 0 ?  <div className='show-hand' onClick={this.deleteFilter(index)}><i style={{ color: 'lightgray' }} className='sane-margin-from-top material-icons'>clear</i></div>  : '' }
                            </div>

                        })
                }
</div>
```

It produces a result something like this:
[image: filters]

Now my problem is that when I am trying to add a text in the textfield, it is somehow refreshing the state and it is moving my cursor away every time. For example, in my first row, if I am trying to enter 'Vikas' in **Filter Value** textfield, As soon as I enter 'V', it refreshes the component and my focus goes away. It looks like I am doing something silly here and somehow messing up the state. My text change method is:

```
filterTextChanged = index => event => {
    const filters = this.state.filters; // or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.filters))
    filters[index].value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ filters });
};
```

So I can see that this approach is totally wrong, but I am unable to find the best approach in such case. If I have a single object in my state, I can easily use that state and update the state only for that object, but how to do it with the Array? Any help? I can find workarounds like using onBlur instead but I really need to find the best approach to use arrays in the state. Any help?

Comment: Just incase someone wonders, this is not related to the component I have built and used, ie "Formatted TextBox". If I replace FormattedTextbox with a normal input, I can reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: can you show a working example?

Comment: Sure @MayankShukla, lemme create a fiddle.

Comment: You have a line onChange={this.filterTextChanged(index)}. So every time you press a key, it launches filterTextChanged. Can you give us what is inside this function? Don't you have a setState there?

Comment: It is already added @FabienLebas, yes I am using setstate.

Comment: Looks like when I tried in fiddle, it worked. So I will see what I did wrong in my code. My hunch was that I may not be using the correct practice but it looks like I am using it correctly.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry, it was a schoolboy error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `key`, you are using the index as the key, but it isn't  identifiable, i.e it will change when you change your filters, try using a uniquer key for each filter that is persisted with state changes and it should fix your problem.

Comment: really? As long as I am not adding or removing items, why would index be changed?

Comment: yeah, you're right, add a fiddle, i think i have an idea

Comment: damn, the same code just works fine in fiddle. So I guess I am on my own :(

Comment: Fixed it, sorry, it was a schoolboy error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you're not keeping your component up to date with the state as you're not setting the `value` of the component. I might be reading the code wrong, but try adding `value={filter.value}` instead of `defaultValue={filter.value}`.

If that doesn't work, a fiddle would be very helpful.